# Не получается вытащить объект из списка. Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Вот отрывок из кода:

```
status = vk.users.get(user_ids=(random.choice(usern)))
stat = status['last_name']
print(stat)
```

После vk.users.get(), мне приходит список:

```
[{'id': 600420495, 'first_name': 'Никита', 'last_name': 'Сафонов', 'is_closed': False, 'can_access_closed': True}]
```

Хочу из списка вытащить только "Сафонов"
Но у меня выходит ошибка:

```
    stat = status['last_name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к элементу словаря. Но забыли обратиться к элементу списка, где лежит этот словарь

Comment: Извините, а как обратится?

Comment: Ну как обращаются к элементам списка?  s[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы начинаете писать ботов для vk, не выучив предварительно Python. Решается - нормальным порядком изучения предмета.

```
stat = status[0]['last_name']
```

Результат:

```
print(stat)
Сафонов
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли!

Comment: Очень хотелось бы, что бы вы обратили внимание на второе предложение моего сообщения.

Comment: Лучшее учение - учение в практике

Comment: Что бы знать что делать, надо понимать как делать. На подсказках зала далеко не уедешь, опыта не наберешься, ничего стоящего не создашь.

Answer (score 2):

`status[0]` вернет первый элемент ответа - это словарь, к элементам словаря уже можно обращаться по ключу: `status[0].get('last_name')`
Нужно помнить что при отсутствии элемента, метод get не вернет ошибку, а значение по умолчанию https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm

Comment: Огромное спасибо!